# A-frame "exit VR" button

Tags: javascript, aframe, virtual-reality

I need to make some simple 3D and 360-image tests using A-frame, for HTML and Oculus, and the "exit vr" button would be very useful in Oculus, but I am a total newbie about programming, and I don't understand how to write events and so on, so the solutions that I find are too high for me to try.

Could anyone show the full code to get a working "exit vr" button? The button could be just an image, or maybe a 3D element.

My code tests are so simple that are not going to be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Add any 3D element (such as a box) to the scene.

Setup cursor and interactions to make the element clickable, find more at:

https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/introduction/interactions-and-controllers.html

https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/cursor.html

Add an onclick function to your clickable entity like this:

`<a-entity onclick="AFRAME.scenes[0].renderer.xr.getSession().end();"></a-entity>`